# What is my 'export PATH=' missing?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, bash

I am on Mac OSX Lion, and somehow in installing mysql and postgres the export PATH line on my .bash_profile got messed up or removed.

So I added in this in an empty .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin
```

But I can't get any bash commands to execute:

```
 /usr/bin $ ls
-bash: ls: command not found

 /usr/bin $ /bin/echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin
```

My .bashrc is probably but not relevant, but in case:

```
[[ -s "/Users/jer/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/jer/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

function _git_prompt() {
    local git_status="`git status -unormal 2>&1`"
    if ! [[ "$git_status" =~ Not\ a\ git\ repo ]]; then
        if [[ "$git_status" =~ nothing\ to\ commit ]]; then
            local ansi=42
        elif [[ "$git_status" =~ nothing\ added\ to\ commit\ but\ untracked\ files\ present ]]; then
            local ansi=43
        else
            local ansi=45
        fi
        if [[ "$git_status" =~ On\ branch\ ([^[:space:]]+) ]]; then
            branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            test "$branch" != master || branch=' '
        else
            # Detached HEAD.  (branch=HEAD is a faster alternative.)
            branch="(`git describe --all --contains --abbrev=4 HEAD 2> /dev/null ||
                echo HEAD`)"
        fi
        echo -n '\[\e[0;37;' "$ansi"';1m\]'"$branch"'\[\e[0m\] '
    fi
}
function _prompt_command() {
    PS1="\n `_git_prompt`"'\n \[\e[1;34m\]\w \$\[\e[0m\] '
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=_prompt_command
#export PS1='\n\[\033[1;33m\]\w\n\[\033[0m\]$(parse_git_branch)$ '
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing `/bin` also possibly `/sbin`.

```
user@host ~ $ which ls
/bin/ls
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, your `PATH` should normally contain: `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/sbin`, followed by any other places you want searched.  (The order listed is my preferred order.  I've also seen all the `bin` paths listed before the `sbin` paths, which I don't mind either.)

Comment: And to elaborate further, this is the default PATH on Lion: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`